# A wrapper class for Telegram bot API in PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented, telegram

I wrote a wrapper class in PHP to use Telegram bot API. What do you think about it?

I used this class in some projects and it doesn't have any problem but I want to know if it is optimized?

```
<?php
/**
 * A wrapper class for telegram bot api
 * you can find source code in https://github.com/smoqadam/php-telegram-bot
 * 
 * @author : Saeed Moqadam <phpro.ir@gmail.com>
 * @licence : MIT Licence
 *
 */
namespace Smoqadam;


class Telegram
{


    const ACTION_TYPING = 'typing';
    const ACTION_UPLOAD_PHOTO = 'upload_photo';
    const ACTION_RECORD_VIDEO = 'record_video';
    const ACTION_UPLOAD_VIDEO = 'upload_video';
    const ACTION_RECORD_AUDIO = 'record_audio';
    const ACTION_UPLOAD_AUDIO = 'upload_audio';
    const ACTION_UPLOAD_DOC = 'upload_document';
    const ACTION_FIND_LOCATION = 'find_location';


    public $api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot';

    /**
     * returned json from telegram api parse to object and save to result
     * @var
     */
    public $result;

    /**
     * commands in regex
     * @var array
     */
    private $commands = [];

    /**
     * callbacks for commands
     * @var array
     */
    private $callbacks = [];

    /**
     * available telegram bot commands
     * @var array
     */
    private $available_commands = [
        'getMe',
        'sendMessage',
        'forwardMessage',
        'sendPhoto',
        'sendAudio',
        'sendDocument',
        'sendSticker',
        'sendVideo',
        'sendLocation',
        'sendChatAction',
        'getUserProfilePhotos',
        'getUpdates',
        'setWebhook',
    ];

    /**
     * pre patterns you can use in regex
     * @var array
     */
    private $patterns = [
        ':any' => '.*',
        ':num' => '[0-9]{0,}',
        ':str' => '[a-zA-z]{0,}',
    ];

    /**
     *
     * @param String $token Telegram api token , taken by botfather
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {

        $this->api .= $token;

    }


    /**
     * add new command to the bot
     * @param String $cmd
     * @param \Closure $func
     */
    public function cmd($cmd, $func)
    {
        $this->commands[] = $cmd;
        $this->callbacks[] = $func;
    }


    /**
     * this method check for recived message(command) and then execute the
     * command function
     *
     * @param bool $sleep
     */
    public function run($sleep = false)
    {

        $result = $this->getUpdates();
        while (true) {

            $update_id = isset($result->update_id) ? $result->update_id : 1;
            $result = $this->getUpdates($update_id + 1);

            $this->processMessage($result);

            if ($sleep !== false)
                sleep($sleep);
        }
    }

    /**
    * this method used for setWebhook sended message
    */
    public function process($message)
    {
            $result = $this->convertToObject($message, true);

            $update_id = isset($result->update_id) ? $result->update_id : 1;

            return $this->processMessage($result);


    }


    private function processMessage($result)
    {
        if ($result) {
                try {
                    $this->result = $result;

                    // message recived by user
                    $recived_command = $this->result->message->text;

                    $args = null;

                    $pos = 0;
                    foreach ($this->commands as $pattern) {

                        // replace public patterns to regex pattern
                        $searchs = array_keys($this->patterns);
                        $replaces = array_values($this->patterns);
                        $pattern = str_replace($searchs, $replaces, $pattern);

                        //find args pattern
                        $args = $this->getArgs($pattern, $recived_command);

                        $pattern = '/^' . $pattern . '/i';

                        preg_match($pattern, $recived_command, $matches);

                        if (isset($matches[0])) {

                            $func = $this->callbacks[$pos];

                            call_user_func($func, $args);

                        }

                        $pos++;

                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    echo "\r\n Exception :: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "\r\nNo new message\r\n";
            }
    }
    /**
     * get arguments part in regex
     * @param $pattern
     * @param $recived_command
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    private function getArgs(&$pattern, $recived_command)
    {

        $args = null;
        // if command has argument
        if (preg_match('/<<.*>>/', $pattern, $matches)) {

            $args_pattern = $matches[0];
            //remove << and >> from patterns

            $tmp_args_pattern = str_replace(['<<', '>>'], ['(', ')'], $pattern);

            //if args set
            if (preg_match('/' . $tmp_args_pattern . '/i', $recived_command, $matches)) {
                //remove first element
                array_shift($matches);

                if (isset($matches[0])) {

                    //set args
                    $args = array_shift($matches);

                    //remove args pattern from main pattern
                    $pattern = str_replace($args_pattern, '', $pattern);

                }
            }
        }
        return $args;
    }


    /**
     * execute telegram api commands
     * @param $command
     * @param array $params
     */
    private function exec($command, $params = [])
    {
        if (in_array($command, $this->available_commands)) {


            // convert json to array then get the last messages info
            $output = json_decode($this->curl_get_contents($this->api . '/' . $command, $params), true);
            return $this->convertToObject($output);


        } else {

            echo 'command not found';

        }
    }


    private function convertToObject($jsonObject , $webhook = false)
    {

        if(!$webhook){
          if ($jsonObject['ok']) {

                // remove unwanted array elements
                $output = end($jsonObject);

                $result = is_array($output) ? end($output) : $output;

                if (!empty($result)) {
                    // convert to object
                    return json_decode(json_encode($result));
                }
            }

        }else{
            if ($jsonObject['message']) {

                    return json_decode(json_encode($jsonObject)); 
                // remove unwanted array elements
                $output = end($jsonObject);

                $result = is_array($output) ? end($output) : $output;

                if (!empty($result)) {
                    // convert to object
                    print_r($result);
                    return json_decode(json_encode($result));
                }
            }
        }


    }

    /**
     * get the $url content with CURL
     * @param $url
     * @param $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function curl_get_contents($url, $params)
    {

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;

    }

    /**
     * Get current chat id
     * @param null $chat_id
     * @return int
     */
    public function getChatId($chat_id = null)
    {
        if ($chat_id)
            return $chat_id;

        return $this->result->message->chat->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param null $offset
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $timeout
     */
    public function getUpdates($offset = null, $limit = 1, $timeout = 1)
    {
        return $this->exec('getUpdates', [
            'offset' => $offset,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'timeout' => $timeout
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * send message
     * @param $text
     * @param $chat_id
     * @param bool $disable_web_page_preview
     * @param null $reply_to_message_id
     * @param null $reply_markup
     */
    public function sendMessage($text, $chat_id, $disable_web_page_preview = false, $reply_to_message_id = null, $reply_markup = null)
    {

        $this->sendChatAction(self::ACTION_TYPING,$chat_id);
        return $this->exec('sendMessage', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'text' => $text,
            'disable_web_page_preview' => $disable_web_page_preview,
            'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Get me
     */
    public function getMe()
    {
        return $this->exec('getMe');
    }


    /**
     * @param $from_id
     * @param $message_id
     * @param null $chat_id
     */
    public function forwardMessage($from_id, $message_id, $chat_id = null)
    {
        return $this->exec('forwardMessage', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'from_chat_id' => $from_id,
            'message_id' => $message_id,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param $photo photo file patch
     * @param null $chat_id
     * @param null $caption
     * @param null $reply_to_message_id
     * @param null $reply_markup
     */
    public function sendPhoto($photo, $chat_id = null, $caption = null, $reply_to_message_id = null, $reply_markup = null)
    {

        $res = $this->exec('sendPhoto', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'photo' => '@' . $photo,
            'caption' => $caption,
            'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);

        return $res;

    }

    /**
     * @param $video video file path
     * @param null $chat_id
     * @param null $reply_to_message_id
     * @param null $reply_markup
     */
    public function sendVideo($video, $chat_id = null, $reply_to_message_id = null, $reply_markup = null)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('sendVideo', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'video' => '@' . $video,
            'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param $sticker
     * @param null $chat_id
     * @param null $reply_to_message_id
     * @param null $reply_markup
     */
    public function sendSticker($sticker, $chat_id = null, $reply_to_message_id = null, $reply_markup = null)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('sendSticker', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'sticker' => '@' . $sticker,
            'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);

        return $res;
        // as soons as possible
    }

    /**
     * @param $latitude
     * @param $longitude
     * @param null $chat_id
     * @param null $reply_to_message_id
     * @param null $reply_markup
     */
    public function sendLocation($latitude, $longitude, $chat_id = null, $reply_to_message_id = null, $reply_markup = null)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('sendLocation', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'latitude' => $latitude,
            'longitude' => $longitude,
            'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * @param $document
     * @param null $chat_id
     * @param null $reply_to_message_id
     * @param null $reply_markup
     */
    public function sendDocument($document, $chat_id = null, $reply_to_message_id = null, $reply_markup = null)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('sendDocument', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'document' => '@' . $document,
            'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);

        return $res;
    }

    public function sendAudio($audio, $chat_id = null, $reply_to_message_id = null, $reply_markup = null)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('sendAudio', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'audio' => '@' . $audio,
            'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * send chat action : Telegram::ACTION_TYPING , ...
     * @param $action
     * @param null $chat_id
     */
    public function sendChatAction($action, $chat_id = null)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('sendChatAction', [
            'chat_id' => $this->getChatId($chat_id),
            'action' => $action
        ]);

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * @param $user_id
     * @param null $offset
     * @param null $limit
     */
    public function getUserProfilePhotos($user_id, $offset = null, $limit = null)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('getUserProfilePhotos', [
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'limit' => $limit
        ]);

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * @param $url
     */
    public function setWebhook($url)
    {
        $res = $this->exec('setWebhook', [
            'url' => $url
        ]);

        return $res;
    }


}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
$tg = new Telegram($api_token);
$tg->cmd('Hi <<:any>>', function ($arg)use ($tg) {
    $tg->sendMessage("Hello $arg",$tg->getChatId());
});
// in cli you must call run() method
$tg->run();

// if you use webhook you have to use $tg->process($message);
```

Answer (score 1):

- `[0-9]{0,}` is more simply written as `\d*`
- `[a-zA-z]{0,}` is more simply/**accurately** written as `[a-z]*` because you are using a case-insensitive pattern in `$pattern` later in the script.
- You may want to validate/sanitize `$token` before doing `$this->api .= $token;`. If you are expecting an alphanumeric string, then maybe `ctype_alnum()`.  I don't know the validation rules of the token, but I don't think I like that the url is being appended with that string without being vetted.
- After a quick glance of `run()` I think you probably want to use a `do{}while()` loop so that you can avoid writing `getUpdates()` twice in your code.
- `$update_id = isset($result->update_id) ? $result->update_id : 1;` could be rewritten with the null coalescing operator as `$update_id = $result->update_id ?? 1;` but I'm not sure this part is working as designed.  Is it supposed to keep incrementing in that loop?  I feel like it is going to get stuck repeating on the first `+ 1`.
- Always use curly braces to mark the body of a condition block.  Too many times have scripts had bugs because the developer tried to save a line of code.  Just use:

  ```
  if ($sleep !== false) {
      sleep($sleep);
  }
  ```
- In `process()`, you have a pointless/ineffectual line of code:

  ```
  $update_id = isset($result->update_id) ? $result->update_id : 1;
  ```

  This overwriting of `$update_id` is useless because this variable is never again accessed in the method.  This raises my concern that your `while(true)` loop is not doing what you expect it to do.  I think you *actually* mean to do *something* with `$result->update_id`.
- `$replaces = array_values($this->patterns);` can be simplified to `$replaces = $this->patterns;` because `str_replace()` will ignore the keys anyhow.  I find the act of calling `str_replace()` to create `$pattern` to be strange.  I mean it will potentially replace replacements.  Perhaps `strtr()` would be more ideal (it happily consumes an associative array anyhow)? I don't know. I am not understanding exactly how this part is working in this context.
- I think I would re-shuffle some of the logic following `//find args pattern` to only define `$args` when necessary and avoid `isset($matches[0])`. Normally I advise against single-use variables, but in this case, maybe there is improved code comprehension by declaring the variables.

  ```
  if (preg_match('/^' . $pattern . '/i', $recived_command, $matches)) {
      $func = $this->callbacks[$pos];
      $args = $this->getArgs($pattern, $recived_command);
      call_user_func($func, $args);
  }
  ```
- I think I need some sample data and expected output to review `getArgs()`.  Overall, I find the code logic to be difficult to follow or indirect (despite the inline comments)
- I think `exec()` should probably throw an exception if the command is not in the whitelist of available commands.  `echo` is probably not enough.
- `convertToObject()` doesn't look very D.R.Y., this part is probably due for a clean up / refactor.
- As a "cute" way to condense an array of associative elements which contain a variable by the same name as the key, [use `compact()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact).

  ```
  compact(['offset', 'limit', 'timeout'])
  ```
- I don't think it is valuable to declare `$res` and then `return $res` immediately after; just return the data and remove the single-use variable declaration.
- Finally, I recommend declaring return types to help you and your IDE to keep your data clean and correct.